# NavigationController is null after logout Menu click in iOS(Xamarin)

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uinavigationcontroller

I am working on Login and Logout in Xamarin.iOS , When I click on Logout Menu using below code it go to LoginViewController.

```
void CalllogoutMethod(ViewController loginController)
        {
            BizApplication.clearCredential();
            NavigationController.PresentViewController(loginController, true, null);
        }
```

But When I again write Username and Password. This time my NavigationController is null why this happen. Login Button click I use below code.

```
var storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName("Main", null);

var webController2 = storyboard.InstantiateViewController("SearchViewController") as SearchViewController;
NavigationController.PushViewController(webController2, true);
```